# Как задать дополнительные свойства классу в тэге button при клике?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть кнопка

```
              <button
                :disabled="clicked.includes(item.id)"
                v-if='item["status"] === 5'
                class="lds-dual-ring"
                @click="changeLoad()"
                v-show="loading"
              >
                  RESTART
              </button>
```

при клике на кнопку нужен такой preloader

```
             <div
                v-if='item["status"] === 5'
                class="lds-dual-ring"
                v-show="loading"
              ></div>
```

Добавляться preloader должен только добавлением одного класса к этой кнопке.Как добавить этот дополнительный класс(при каком-то условии)?

Comment: возможно, это можно сделать так `@click="loading = !loading"`

Comment: Спасибо за отклик .У меня этим занимается функция changeLoad(). Мне просто нужно , чтобы лоадер было видно когда кнопку с тэга template убираешь,где находиться этот button. Сейчас его видно только при наведении на template.

Comment: мне ничего не понятно. Покажите код, который воспроизводит проблему

Comment: Есть самая стандартная кнопка button, как мне добавить к ней дополнительные стили при каком-то условии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так можно добавить стили динамически во vue.js через `:class`, например класс `active`. Если `loading` будет `true`, то класс добавится:

```
<button
  :disabled="clicked.includes(item.id)"
  v-if='item["status"] === 5'
  class="lds-dual-ring"
  :class="{
      'active': loading
      'button-default': !loading
  }"
  @click="changeLoad()"
  v-show="loading"
>
  RESTART
</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как мне указать класс по умолчанию для button? Если loading будет false..

Comment: @epileptickid дополнил ответ)

Comment: А если я хочу указать по умолчанию совсем другой класс, например class="button-default". Когда lds-dual-ring будет в состоянии 'no active'. Как мне это указать в коде?

Comment: @epileptickid так? https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html вот ссылка про работу с динамическими классами во vue.js)